# AWS SSL Certificate export

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I have generated a SSL certificate through aws certificate manager, now I would like to export so that I can use it with my in-house hosted server applications. Please advise how to do it.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we export a \*public\* certificate from AWS Certificate Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133631/why-cant-we-export-a-public-certificate-from-aws-certificate-manager)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you used ACM to create a Public Certificate. If that is the case then it is not possible to use it for on Prem applications. ACM certificates are deployed through Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon CloudFront, Amazon API Gateway, and other integrated AWS services. Check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html)